# I have made a simple layout for my calculator. In the IDE it looks OK, but on my phone, mate 8 it looks completely different

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Android studio it looks the way I want it but it looks different on my mate 8 than on my tablet

> on my tablet:
>   [how it shows on my tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmPn8.png)

[how it shows on my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArYmb.png)

**THIS IS THE MAIN ACTIVITY:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_userInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1+2+3+4"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"

            />

<include
            layout="@layout/calc_buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

> **THIS IS A GRID LAYOUT IN ANOTHER LAYOUT ACTIVITY:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:rowCount="5"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"

    >

    <!--1st line of buttons-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Clear"
        android:text="C"
        style="@style/FunctionalButtons"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"

        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Percentage"
        android:text="%"
        style="@style/FunctionalButtons"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"

        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Divide"
        android:text="/"
        style="@style/FunctionalButtons"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
<!--2nd line of buttons-->
<!--3rd line of buttons -->
```

> **etc**

```
 </GridLayout>
```

> I have omitted most of the repetitive code such as the buttons for
>   readability.

Comment: (shoulda just used constraint layout with horizontal and vertical chains with packed style, grid layout doesn't really work tbh)